# A way to implement counter in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm searching a way to implement a counter of question  in JQuery and the problem is that JQuery is a functionnal language. I have a quiz with a label "Question number n" where n is the number of the question. I have  two buttons : one allow to you to add a question and the other one allow the delete the question.

How can I do that with a functional language ? Now, I have a version with use a global variable and I  think there is a better way to use a such variable ..

Comment: What is your question? Where is your relevant code? What about using CSS counter instead?

Comment: Show us your code, then we'll see how to do this in a better way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implement in my code it is useful for you to began [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJUF3/1/)

```
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="delete">delete</button>
<div id="question"> text</div>
```

jquery

```
var count = 0;

$("#add").on("click" , function() { 
    count = count + 1;
    $("#question").text(count);
});

$("#delete").on("click" , function() { 
    if(count > 0) {
      count = count - 1;
      $("#question").text(count);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have something which look like your code and the problem is that this code use a global variable (your variable count). Is it a way to implement a counter without a global variable ?

Comment: I just update the edited code in fiddle. Now use data() in jquery didn't use global variable please check and let me know thanks

Comment: Oh great ! This is exactly what I want !